# Hide all the icon [android sdk]

Tags: android, icons, hide, wallpaper

I am making a live wallpaper for android. I want to implement a function that allow user hide all the icon from the screen of android to show off the live wallpaper(User double click to screen -> hide all the icon). I made everything but I still dont know how to hide all the icons. Anyone know how?
Thank

Comment: What did you try? Can you put some code to show us how are you doing things?

Comment: I have no idea to implement function: hide all the icons, so I have no code to show you. I do google around 2-3 hours but still not find any idea to do that. Any idea?(sorry, my bad english). I can hide my own application's icon by removing TAG: <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />. But it is not for other apps.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible. You cannot attack the home screen, or other apps, in this fashion. A home screen may not even *have* "icons", depending upon its implementation.

You are welcome to write your own home screen, or perhaps partner with the developers of some replacement home screens, to have this feature implemented *by the home screen*.

Or, IIRC, there is a way to show a live wallpaper as the background of an activity, though I am not certain of the details. If that is indeed possible, to "show off the live wallpaper", you would offer an activity to do so, one that has nothing in the foreground.